# Average out two list Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to conjoin two list to get average's
Not of the entire list but element to element (cross fire between both list)

```
listone = [5,5,5,6,7,8,9]
listtwo = [4,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

listone contains the number of dentist that were asked to fill a survey per say
and listwo would be how many of those dentist sported, example for 0,0 4 out of 5 Dentist recommend this toothpaste.

the long way would be

```
x = (listwo[0:1]/listone[0:1]#4/5
l = x*100 ## (4/5) * 100 = 80
xt =(listwo[1:2]/listone[1:2]#2/5
lt= xt*100 ##(2/5)*100= 40
print("In a survey,l+"% of Dentist recommended this toothpaste")
```

But the problem is that I dont know how to conjoin two list in a loop to get the percentage.
Thank you.

Comment: @hd1 Thank you but, I need to get the average per element not per list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a basic `for` loop:

```
listone = [5,5,5,6,7,8,9]
listtwo = [4,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for _ in range(len(listone)):
    x, y = listone[_], listtwo[_]
    value = y/float(x)*100
    print "In a survey %.2f%% of dentists recommend this toothpaste" % value
```

**Runs as:**

```
In a survey 80.00% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 40.00% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 60.00% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 66.67% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 71.43% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 75.00% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 77.78% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
```

Or you can use `zip()`:

```
listone = [5,5,5,6,7,8,9]
listtwo = [4,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for x, y in zip(listone, listtwo):
    value = y/float(x)*100
    print "In a survey %.2f%% of dentists recommend this toothpaste" % value
```

**Runs as:**

```
In a survey 80.00% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 40.00% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 60.00% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 66.67% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 71.43% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 75.00% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
In a survey 77.78% of dentists recommend this toothpaste
```

As you can see, `zip()` creates a list of tuples from both the lists:

```
>>> zip(listone, listtwo)
[(5, 4), (5, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 6), (9, 7)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to zip the lists together

```
for x, y in zip(listone, listtwo):

    print "In a survey {} % of dentists recommend this toothpaste".format(y/float(x) * 100)
```

Zipping two lists creates a list of tuples, the first element in the first tuple is the element at index 0 in the first list, the second element in the first tuple is the element at index 0 in the second list, and so on.

Comment: `float` not needed in Python 3